# JPA Hibernate @OneToMany fails to insert children

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have an entity called "Review" that has a `@OneToMany` relationship with a `ReviewStage` entity.  Very simple in my mind.

My database looks like this:

`Review` table:

- review_id
- name

`Stage` table:

- stage_id
- review_id
- name

`Review` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long reviewId;
    private String name;
 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "reviewId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ReviewStage> stages;
}
```

`ReviewStage` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class ReviewStage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long stageId;
    private Long reviewId;
    private String name;
}
```

I post the following JSON to my Service:

```
{
    "reviewId": 0,
    "name": "TEST",
    "stages": [{
        "stageId": 0,
        "reviewId": 0,
        "name": "Stage 1"
    }]
}
```

> JDBC Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The
> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_er_review_stage_er_review". The conflict occurred in database
> "ereviewdev", table "dbo.review", column 'review_id'.

What am I missing? I tried to put `@Transactional` in my Service class but, it didn't have any affect. Seems simple.

Comment: Perhaps debug to find out what the actual object graph is that Hibernate is about to store? Or activate Hibernate SQL debugging to see the actual SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, I see the prepared sql statement - it is correct.  The reviewId generated from the parent table "Review" is not being used in the child table "ReviewStage" to insert the child record.

Answer (score 1):

The [following mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

```java
@Entity
public class Review {
 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "reviewId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ReviewStage> stages;

    public Review() {
       stages = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addStage(ReviewStage stage) {
        stages.add(stage);
        stage.setReview(this);
    }

    public void removeStage(ReviewStage stage) {
        stages.remove(stage);
        stage.setReview(null);
    }
}
```

assumes that you have the following child side.

```java
@Entity
public class ReviewStage {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id")
    private Review reviewId;
}
```

but you have:

```java
@Entity
public class ReviewStage {

    private Long reviewId;
}
```

**EDIT**
An example how you should save new `Review`:

```java
Review review = new Review();
review.setName("New review");

ReviewStage stage1 = new ReviewStage();
ReviewStage stage2 = new ReviewStage();
review.addStage(stage1);
review.addStage(stage2);
reviewRepository.save(review);
```

Comment: I tried this small change and now I cannot fetch a reveiw: Invalid column name 'review_id_review_id'.  Am I forced to make it bi-directional?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the fetch but, not the problem. @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "review", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ReviewStage> stages;  --- and in ReviewStage --- @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reviewId", nullable = false )
    private Review review;    - but, I still get the null error when trying to insert review_id

Comment: If you use `mappedBy` on the `@OneToMany` than yes, it should be bi-directional. It looks like you should add `@JoinColumn(name = "review_id")`

Comment: and one more requirement of bidirectional relationship: *the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times*. What means you should provide the utility methods that synchronize both ends whenever a child element is added or removed.

Comment: I don't need bi-directional.  Just need to cascade the insert from JSON.  I've tried JoinColumn and still same error.  It does the insert into Review table but, then, the next insert into ReviewStage does not have the review_id - like it's in a separate transaction?  In JDBC you would use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to get the newly inserted id then, use it for detail records.

Comment: To save the Review, I'm usinga JpaRespository - reviewRepository.save(review).  review has stages and it is failing to insert each stage to the review because it's not getting the review_id from the newly inserted review.

Comment: 1. I have added an example how you can save new review with several stages. 2. As I understand you want just get entities from the requested json and save it (no matter it is old review/stages or not). If this it true I must upset - it will not be possible.

Comment: I am trying to insert a new review with new stages.  No records exist in the database.

Comment: You should not set the `ReviewStage.stageId` and `Review.reviewId` for the new entities. When you use the [GenerationType.IDENTITY](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity) id generation strategy they are generated by database.